# Custom helper: class not found. Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, helper

I've created a custom new file, app/Http/Helpers.php and added:

```
<?php

namespace app\Http;

class ConnectionsHelper {

    public static function organisation($id) {
       return 'ID:'.$id;
   }
}
```

In Composer.json, in the autoload-block I've added:

```
"files": [ 
    "app/Http/Helpers.php" 
]
```

And then I ran "composer dump-autoload".

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class myController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo ConnectionsHelper::organisation(2);
    }
}
```

And get in return:

```
FatalErrorException in OrganisationsController.php:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ConnectionsHelper' not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a namespace alias in your controller.

```
use App\Http\ConnectionsHelper
```

Autoloading a file does not mean that the classes in that file are required/included in all other scripts in the app. It just means that you are making those files *available* to your app. In this case, your helper file is already inside the `App` namespace which is autoloaded by default, so you can remove the `files` bit of your composer.json completely.